# Customize AWS cognito sign in page CSS through cognitoConfig.yaml file

Tags: css, yaml, amazon-cognito

I am automating the creating userpool process in AWS Cognito.  I am using a yaml file to set the whole thing (i.e. user attributes, IDP, etc...).  I need to customize the sign in page, and I know enough that I need to add CSS to specific list of classes.  I don't understand where or the format.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I did it. You can now make use of the AWS::Cognito::UserPoolIdentityProvider resource

```
UserPoolUICustomization: 
Type: AWS::Cognito::UserPoolUICustomizationAttachment 
Properties: 
  UserPoolId: !Ref CognitoUserPool
  ClientId: !Ref CognitoUserPoolClient2 
  CSS: ".logo-customizable {
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
  }
       .banner-customizable {
    padding: 0px 0px 5px 0px;
    background-color: #fff;
  }
       .label-customizable {
    font-weight: 400;
  }
       .textDescription-customizable {
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    display: block;
    font-size: 16px;
  }
       .idpDescription-customizable {
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    display: block;
    font-size: 16px;
  }
       .legalText-customizable {
    color: #747474;
    font-size: 11px;
  }
       .submitButton-customizable {
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin: 20px 0px 10px 0px;
    height: 40px;
    width: 100%;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #337ab7;
  }"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the css classes provided and use AWS CLI to push updates.

```
background-customizable
banner-customizable
errorMessage-customizable
idpButton-customizable
idpButton-customizable:hover
inputField-customizable
inputField-customizable:focus + few more.
```

AWS provides the list of classes used on cognito user pool UI which you can modify.

use `--css ".classname{field : value}"` with `aws cognito-idp set-ui-customization` command to update.

Like :-

```
aws cognito-idp set-ui-customization --user-pool-id <your-user-pool-id> --client-id 
<your-app-client-id> --image-file <path-to-logo-image-file> --css ".label-
customizable{ color: <color>;}"
```

Comment: I want to add this as part of the yaml file so that it is built and done in one shot without having to go back in with the cli or sdk.